# Mysql shell table formatting issue

Tags: mysql, shell

When i do `select * from users limit 10`
I get output in mysql shell but it's not formatted so I cannot see properly.

Is there a way to output tabular format and also would you be able to recommend any GUI tool other than phpMyAdmin because it's not installed in this virtual server?

Comment: I've a great time with [Emma](http://freecode.com/projects/emma).

Comment: FYI you can install phpMyAdmin yourself - in case you weren't aware.

Comment: Is it not formatted because of some display problem, or because your terminal is too small?  Have you tried enlarging the terminal so that the largest row can fit within the width you've resized to?  Alternatively, try using \G to terminate the statement for a different output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* tabular, it's just that the table is wider than your display so it wraps each line.

Any client listed on the MySQL site (and anywhere else for that matter) will work once you have a SSH tunnel opened to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I remember MySql has its own software with a friendly GUI to manage databases.
did you have a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

--edit--

or here http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 1):

If it contains too many columns you can always select fewer columns or use the following query with `\G`.

```
select * from users limit 10\G
```

This will show your columns vertically. But it may become very long.